# Type inference for System F-omega

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-checking, type-inference

There have been some nice papers about simple type inference for System F: ["HMF: Simple Type Inference for First-Class Polymorphism"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/hmf.pdf), ["Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/putting.pdf), and ["Complete and Easy Bidirectional Typechecking
for Higher-Rank Polymorphism"](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~nk480/bidir.pdf). These algorithms require varying amounts of annotations from the user in order to do the type inference.
I am unable to find any papers on how to do type inference for System F-omega though. My questions:

1. Can the above algorithms be extended to handle System F-omega (maybe with some more required annotations)? Or do the type lambdas require a different approach?
2. Given that explicitly typed (Church-style) System F-omega is easy to type check, could we use one of the above algorithms to do type inference on the System F subset while requiring explicit types for the type lambdas, or do the type lambdas "infect" the other parts so that we cannot do this.
3. Is type inference for System F-omega simpler than type inference for dependent types or do they basically need the same techniques (higher-order unification)?